# Set Query Parameters on a Jersey Test Call

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have a Jersey based Java servlet:

```
@Path("foo")
class Foo {
  @GET
  @Path("bar")
  public Response bar(@QueryParam("key") String value) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I can call it in Tomcat just fine as:

```
http://localhost:8080/container/foo/bar?key=blah
```

However, in my JerseyTest, using Grizzly, it's not handling the parameters properly. This test case returns a 404 error:

```
@Test
public void testBar() {
  final Response response = target("foo/bar?key=blah").request().get();
}
```

I suspect the issue is it's looking for a resource named `foo/bar?key=blah` rather than trying to pass `key=blah` to the resource at `foo/bar`. If I pass just `"foo/bar"` to `target()`, I get a 500, as the code throws an exception for a null parameter.

I looked through the Jersey Test documentation, and some examples, and I found some cryptic looking stuff that might have been for passing parameters to a GET, but none of it looked like it was assigning values to parameters, so I wasn't positive how I would use it.

How can I pass my value in for that parameter?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

JavaDoc to [WebTarget.queryParam()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) should give you an answer to your problem. Basically you need to transform your code to something like:

```
target("foo/bar").queryParam("key", "blah").request().get()
```

Comment: Just a hint: make sure you call `queryParam` before `request`. The fluent API won't allow it afterwards. Took me a minute.

Comment: what can I use for post request?

Comment: how to add multiple params multiple keys ?